# Powershell performance : nested foreach vs foreach in series

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am doing some performance profiling on registry search, and I have found a definite performance difference between these two loop structures, and I wonder what is going on under the hood to explain it? From a readability standpoint I prefer the nested foreach (Loops2) over the loops in series (Loops1). However, Loops1 consistently runs in about 55% of the time of Loops2. Now, to be honest I don't know that it REALLY matters, given that I am running each loop 100 times and the slow one is still under 1 second (.88) and in actual use I will likely not run the loop even half as many times as that, often much lower. But I feel like just the fact that I am doing the performance profiling is a real improvement in my approach, and understanding WHY one performs better than the other would be valuable too. I may well use the slower approach because of readability, but perhaps there is something in the why that will convince me otherwise.

```
$regKeys = @('Registry::HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', 
             'Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall')
$regKeyNames = @('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', 
                 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall')
$searchPropertyValue = 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x64) - 11.0.61030'

Write-Host "`r`nLoops1 " -noNewLine
(Measure-Command {
    foreach ($i in 1..100) {
        $installedPrograms = Get-ChildItem -Path:$regKeys[0]
        :x64 foreach ($installedProgram in $installedPrograms) {
            if ($installedProgram.GetValue('DisplayName') -eq $searchPropertyValue) {
                $found = $installedProgram
                break x64
            }
        }
        if (-not $found) {
            $installedPrograms = Get-ChildItem -Path:$regKeys[1]
            :x32 foreach ($installedProgram in $installedPrograms) {
                if ($installedProgram.GetValue('DisplayName') -eq $searchPropertyValue) {
                    $found = $installedProgram
                    break x32
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).TotalSeconds
Write-Host "$found"

Write-Host "`r`nLoops2 " -noNewLine 
(Measure-Command {
    foreach ($i in 1..100) {
        :search foreach ($key in $regKeys) {
            $installedPrograms = Get-ChildItem -Path:$key
            foreach ($installedProgram in $installedPrograms) {
                if ($installedProgram.GetValue('DisplayName') -eq $searchPropertyValue) {
                    $found = $installedProgram
                    break search
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).TotalSeconds
Write-Host "$found"

Write-Host "`r`n[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive] " -noNewLine 
(Measure-Command {
    $localMachineHive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, 0)


foreach ($i in 1..100) {
        :search foreach ($keyName in $regKeyNames) {
            if (($installedProgram = $localMachineHive.OpenSubKey("$keyName\$uninstallKeyName")).GetValue('DisplayName') -eq $searchPropertyValue1) {
                $found = $installedProgram
                break search
            }
        }
    }
}).TotalSeconds
Write-Host "$found"
```

Comment: Have you tried swapping the order of the tests or running them in separate PowerShell sessions to make sure that doesn't affect results? (e.g. Garbage collection from Loop1 might be triggered during Loop2). And maybe increase your iterations to something 10,000 to reduce the proportional impact of external events. 55% of 0.88 seconds is a very short window to draw conclusions about, but if you get a 55% improvement on 88 seconds that's a bit more concrete...

Comment: @mclayton I have tried just doing the same pair of tests, in the same order again, and reversed the order. And I just ran it again with 1000 iterations, as well as variations that find the program in the first registry key rather than the second. When the property is found in the first key, both approaches are basically the same, but when the second loop is required, nested is still consistently slower. At 1000 iterations it's 8.3 seconds vs 4.7. When the property is found in the first key, nested is a tiny bit faster, 4.5 seconds vs 4.7. Different sessions doesn't seem to affect it at all.

Comment: Not affecting it meaning 1000 iterations, found in the second key, separate sessions, nested is around 10 seconds, series is 6, no matter which session I run first. Both (ISE) sessions on screen at the same time. I haven't tried running console sessions totally independently yet.

Comment: And, running in the console doesn't change things, nested, second key, consistently slower.

Comment: Also worth testing is a variant that does not use`Get-ChildItem`, which is notoriously slow. Instead, use the [`RegistryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=net-6.0) class directly.

Comment: @zett42 Interesting. New to me, and I definitely need to play with that. So far I can get the subway names, and unfortunately it gets the GUID based names last, and that's what I am usually looking for. But if it's enough faster then iterating through all the other non GUID keys first might not be a problem.

Comment: Holy cow! `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]` is a massive improvement. 1000 iterations, with a target found in the second key, and using the nested loop that is slower with `Get-ChildItem', and I get times of ONE second, vs 4 and 8 for the other two approaches. I think we have a winner. :)

Comment: That said, I WOULD still like to know why the two loop structures have such different performance. :)